# Sonar-Scanner : Error java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: javascript, java, sonarqube

I'm trying to set up Sonarqube for the project. I managed to configure it about a month ago but there I encounter an error. The error may occur for other things than Sonarqube, so if you know how to solve it I am a taker. The mistake is when I run the command : "sonar-scanner" in my project folder.

Error occurred during initialization of VM

java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

I tried :

- Restart my computer (LOL)
- Java Update
- Install Java
- Empty Java caches
- Update Sonarqube
- Try Sonar-Runner (old version of the Sonar-Scanner, if I understood correctly)
- Install Sonar-Scanner
- Check that I have enough RAM for the VM
- Check my Java with a Simple class

My Environment :

openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)

javac 12.0.1

MacOS Mojave version 10.14.5

sonarqube 7.8

sonar-scanner 3.3.0.1492

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in eclipse.

The latest version of SonarLint for IntelliJ (4.0.1) includes a fix for the problem.

If not try including it in jenkins, please check and let us know.

Comment: Hi Arun ! Thanks for answer ! 

There is a SonarLint for VScode. But that does not solve my problem, because the problem occurs in the console, when I enter the command line "Sonar-Scanner". My application is Javascript, I do not think it changes anything but you never know. 

If you think I misunderstood your answer, give me more details about how to deal with SonarLint. Thank you